# Spring Boot scheduler issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduling

I have a simple Spring Boot app that handles some REST API calls and so on. I added `@EnableScheduling` to my main class and then proceeded to add `@Scheduled` on top of each function I need to schedule and then added a cron expression.

Spring boot Version : 2.7.1

What I have is the following:

I have three classes. Each class contains a void function scheduled.

I ran the app and everything seems working fine. All the API calls ran smoothly and as excepted, and then I ran the same app but from a jar file using the cmd. The scheduler works fine the first day and then suddenly stops working and then starts working again the day after.

I was monitoring the logs and it turned out that 4 out of 5 days the scheduler ran as expected, but skipped one day for no reason.

Any one might experienced this weird behavior?

main class:

```java
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class MYCLASSHERE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MYCLASSHERE.class, args);
    }
}
```

each class has the following structure:

```java
@Service
public class MYOTHERCLASS{
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 12 * * *")
    public void FUNCTION() {}
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MYOTHERCLASS{
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 12 * * *")
    public void FUNCTION() {}
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MYOTHERCLASS{
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 12 * * *")
    public void FUNCTION() {}
}
```

Note that everything is working fine. The scheduler stoppage that I'm experiencing is the only problem when running from a jar file.

Comment: share all your relevant code

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos i added a snippet from the code as it shows most of the working  code

Comment: How long do your methods take on production? Could it be a missed schedule? Did you explicitly configure a `TaskScheduler` or defined properties for it in Spring Boot?

Comment: @M.Deinum it's around 1- 2 min that's why I separated them with 5 min

Comment: But is it really 1 to 2 minutes on production? What if there is a connection hiccup? What if it does take longer? Which `TaskScheduler` you use?

Comment: i used the default one configured by spring  itself @Scheduled is used no configuration is done from my side so ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

Comment: @Mhamadjawadalhajjar please check if you can replicate the  issue. If yes then it should be considered a bug of spring

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos yes that's what I'll do, any tips on a way for replicating this issue or just scheduling and monitoring ?

Answer (score 1):

try @Scheduled(cron = "0 35,40 14 * * ?") for your function

Comment: thanks for your comment but is it going to affect the scheduler Not working problem because as it is it's working fine so don't know what "?" in the year value would change
and i updated the time values just to be accurate

Comment: An explanation of why this would solve the problem would be helpful.